# Help in a proof in Sharp's Steps in Commutative Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I'm studying the Sharp's book of commutative algebra, and I need a help in this proof why $S_0$ is a subalgebra of $S$, maybe because my lack of experience of this subject, I found myself a little lost in this part of the demonstration.

[image]

See using the definition of subalgebra, $S_0$ has to be a subring of $S$ and the image of the homomorphism related to the R-algebra $f:R\to S$ has to be contained in $S_0$, I couldn't proof the latter statement.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is hard to answer not because it is difficult, but because I am not sure what you're stuck on. My suggestion is to write down the definition of an $R$-(sub)algebra and then tell us which properties you're having trouble verifying.

Comment: @KarlKronenfeld thank you for the remark, is it ok now?

Comment: Just a comment: this is the celebrated [Artin-Tate lemma](http://commalg.wiki-site.com/index.php/Artin-Tate_lemma).

Comment: @YACP thank you for the comment, very good to know this.

Answer (score 2):

Let's first see how $S$ is regarded as an $R$-algebra. The fact that it is a ring is given; but the the map $f:R\to S$ is not given specifically. Here, and usually when $R\subseteq S$, it is implied that $f$ is the identity map $S\to S$ restricted to $R$. That is, $f(r)=r$ for all $r\in R$. (Using this type of map, we actually see that any ring that contains $R$ is automatically an $R$-algebra.)

Now, it's straight forward. The image of $f:R\to S$ is $R$, which is a subset of $S_0=R[\Gamma\cup\Delta]$; this is exactly the property of $S_0$ you needed to show.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The trick was the identity map as the structural homomorphism $f:R\to S$, I didn't know that is usual to consider the identity map when $R\subset S$.

Comment: But one question surges in my mind, can I choose any structural homomorphism to solve these type of questions? for example instead to use the identity map, it would change anything if I use another one?

Comment: @user42912: In theory, you can use any endomorphism of $R$, but you have to be consistent to get everything to work. What I mean is that an $R$-algebra homomorphism $\varphi:S\to T$ (where $f:R\to S$ and $g:R\to T$ are the relevant ring maps) must *preserve scalars*, i.e. $$\varphi(f(r))=g(r)\quad\text{for all }r\in R$$ If $R$ were contained in both $S$ and $T$, and $f$ were the identity and $g$ were some nonidentity endomorphism then a map that "should" be an $R$-algebra map would not be one.